# Draw a figure with text in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to make this figure in LaTeX:[image]
But i'm really noob using Tikz, I search in this page and some pages and this is what I got:
[image]

I know that the result is not very good but I don't know how to improve it and I have the following problems and questions:

1. Are the coordinates necessary? When this figure be ready I need to put it in a Beamer and I don't know if I'll have a problem when I try to do that.
2. There is a way to more automatically the braces? (Like the arrows using the nodes that I've created just referencing the nodes created)
3. How could I make the text "Relacion de Agencia" and "PROBLEMA DE AGENCIA" in 3 different lines (just as the photo) and also being centered?
4. It is possible to make an aligned text with the text "(i) Conflicto de intereses" "(ii) Asimetría de información"? Because the original concept has an space between the "(i)" and "(ii)" respectively.
5. Searching in this page I've found a package called Forest because a guy use it in this type of figures, is it recommendable?

This is my really basic code, thanks to anyone that could help me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
% nodes
\node (M) at (-5, 0) {Monitor};
\node (P) at (-3, 2) {Principal};
\node (A) at (-3, -2) {Agente};
\node (RDA) at (0, 0) {Relacion de Agencia};
\node (i) at (3, 2) {(i) Conflicto de intereses};
\node (ii) at (3, -2) {(ii) Asimetría de información};
\node (PDA) at (6, 0) {PROBLEMA DE AGENCIA};


% arrows
\draw[->] (P) -- (A);
\draw[dashed, ->] (P) -- (M);
\draw[dashed, -] (M) -- (A);
\draw[->] (RDA) -- (i);
\draw[->] (RDA) -- (ii);

% braces
\draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}, decorate] (-2, 2) node {} -- (-2 , -2);
\draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}, decorate] (5.5, 2) node {} -- (5.5 , -2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ comes with a manual with lots of tutorials.

Comment: You might want to undo the edit as some people will find it helpful.

Comment: After your editing of your question it become unclear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a starting point. I think you could improve it.

I changed the positioning of nodes and so its order of appearance. Also, I changed the arrow heads.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={baseline=base, node distance=5cm},
  arrow/.style={-latex, thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (M) {Monitor};
\node[above right of = M] (P)  {Principal};
\node[below right of = M] (A)  {Agente};

\draw[decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=2pt}, decorate] (P.north east)  --node[right=.5cm,align=center] (RDA) {Relacion\\ de\\ Agencia} (A.south east -| P.east);

\node[align=left,right of=P,yshift=-1.5cm] (i)  {\llap{(i)\ }Conflicto de\\ intereses};
\node[align=left,right of=A,yshift=1.5cm] (ii)  {\llap{(ii) }Asimetría de\\ información};

\draw[decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=2pt}, decorate] (ii.south east) --node[right=.5cm,align=center] (PDA)  {PROBLEMA\\ DE\\ AGENCIA} (i.north east -| ii.east)  ;

\node at ($(i)!.5!(ii)$){$+$};

\draw[arrow] (P) -- (A);
\draw[arrow,dashed] (P.south west) -- (M);
\draw[arrow,dashed] (M) -- (A.north west);
\draw[arrow] (RDA) -- (i.south west);
\draw[arrow] (RDA) -- (ii.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ```\draw[arrow,dashed] (M) -- (A.north west);``` should be replaced by ```\draw[dashed] (M) -- (A.north west);``` (compared to the author's sketch).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed, I really appreciate your time helping me. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You're using the old deprecated syntax, not the syntax of the `positioning` library. It should be `right=of`, not `right of=`.